# Rake or Rails db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to RoR and am starting on the guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html .

When I run the command `bin/rails db:migrate`, I get the error `command db:migrate not recognized`

But I am able to run the command `bin/rake db:migrate` without any issues.

My question is : is there any difference between the two or can I just rest easy and use rake? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on version of Rails.
Before Rails 5.0 it was

```
rake db:migrate
```

Starting from Rails 5.0 it is

```
rails db:migrate
```

From changelog:

> One Rails Command instead of the split-brain setup between rake and
>   rails, so now it’s `bin/rails db:migrate` instead of `bin/rake db:migrate`

See [changelog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/) for full list of  changes in Rails 5.

Answer (score 4):

Rails is framework.

Rake is a standalone Ruby utility that replaces the Unix utility ‘make’, and uses a ‘Rakefile’ and .rake files to build up a list of tasks. In Rails, Rake is used for common administration tasks, especially sophisticated ones that build off of each other.”

You can view more : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-rake.htm

Answer (score 2):

Which version of rails gem are you using? In rails 5 (the guide you linked is for rails 5) we use rails command for everything. Before rails 5 we used rake for db commands.

Comment: I am using rails 4.2.5.. hm I should update my rails version then.. thanks!